# Stop text from moving other divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a table and if I change text which is different length it moves other things as well. To make it more clear here's my Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/5uys473u/

As you can see by using name "Richard" moves other text more right than using name "James". My question is how can I fix it? Whatever amount/name I enter there I don't want it to move I just want other things stay like being "Fixed".

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Testing Box</h3>
    <div class="borderBox test">
        <div id="scroll-scroll">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="information">
                    <span class="spantext2">#000001</span>
                    <span class="fixed-names">Name: <span class="spantext2">Richard</span></span>
                    Amount: <span class="spantext2">5,000$</span>
                    <span class="icon-margin2"><img src="/static/images/ic_compare_arrows_black_24dp_1x.png"></span> Date: <span class="spantext2">01/07/2017</span> Status: <span class="spantext2">Pending</span> New Amount: <span class="spantext2 floating">5,000$</span>
                </div>
                <div class="separate-line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="information">
                    <span class="spantext2">#000001</span>
                    <span class="fixed-names">Name: <span class="spantext2">James</span></span>
                    Amount: <span class="spantext2">5,000$</span>
                    <span class="icon-margin2"><img src="/static/images/ic_compare_arrows_black_24dp_1x.png"></span> Date: <span class="spantext2">01/07/2017</span> Status: <span class="spantext2">Pending</span> New Amount: <span class="spantext2 floating">5,000$</span>
                </div>
                <div class="separate-line"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-md-6{
    font-family: Norwester;
    color: #891b15;
}
.borderBox{
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.test{
    height: 162px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#scroll-scroll{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
.information{
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
.info{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
.spantext2{
    margin: 0px 11px;
    color: #891b15;
}
.separate-line{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 13px 0px 13px;
}
.icon-margin2{
    margin: 0 18px;
}
.floating{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You could turn some of those spans into inline blocks and specify their sizes in CSS. But it seems it might be better to actually use tables for this, as it will handle the sizing for you.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks, but I just want everything to stay in place if text is added there no matter of the length.

Comment: Then the inline-block route is probably where you want to go (I see that @musheng-wu has already added an answer with that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to set width of "name".

try this.

```
.fixed-names > .spantext2 {
  width: 80px; /* fixed size you want */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML and CSS like below and start leveraging Flexbox :)

```css
.col-md-6{
 font-family: Norwester;
 color: #891b15;
}
.borderBox{
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.test{
 height: 162px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#scroll-scroll{
 overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
.information{
margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;}
.info{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
.spantext2{
 margin: 0px 11px;
    color: #891b15;
    flex: 1;
}
.separate-line{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 13px 0px 13px;
}
.icon-margin2{
 margin: 0 18px;
}
.floating{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Testing Box</h3>
    <div class="borderBox test">
        <div id="scroll-scroll">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="information">
                    <span class="spantext2">#000001</span>
                    <span class="spantext2">Name: Richard</span>
                    Amount: <span class="spantext2">5,000$</span>
                    <span class="icon-margin2"><img src="/static/images/ic_compare_arrows_black_24dp_1x.png"></span> Date: <span class="spantext2">01/07/2017</span> Status: <span class="spantext2">Pending</span> New Amount: <span class="spantext2 floating">5,000$</span>
                </div>
                <div class="separate-line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="information">
                    <span class="spantext2">#000001</span>
                    <span class="spantext2">Name: James</span>
                    Amount: <span class="spantext2">5,000$</span>
                    <span class="icon-margin2"><img src="/static/images/ic_compare_arrows_black_24dp_1x.png"></span> Date: <span class="spantext2">01/07/2017</span> Status: <span class="spantext2">Pending</span> New Amount: <span class="spantext2 floating">5,000$</span>
                </div>
                <div class="separate-line"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```